# Is DateTime.Parse COM dependent

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, com

I ran across a blog entry that stated `DateTime.Parse` is COM dependent. I have not been able to find confirming evidence for this statement.

If this is the case I would like to find documentation on this preferably sourced from Microsoft.

Source: http://blog.aasheim.org/2008/04/dont-use-datetimeparse-use.html

Comment: Why does it matter? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you have a link to this article?

Comment: Initially I was researching why DateTime.Parse was so slow which lead to more detailed questions.  It matters to me because 1) the deeper you understand your tools the better you are as a developer. Knowing the edge cases can come in very handy  2) because I am neurotic and compulsively burrow

Comment: In general it's true that understanding your tools is important. But this method is *specifically* designed to be a black-box that you call without it being relevant how it's implemented under the covers. In fact, it could change at any time, which is probably why the implementation is *not* documented. If you care about this sort of thing, download a copy of [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) (or equivalent) and see the implementation of the .NET Framework internals yourself. But if the method does what you want, call it. If not, use something else.

Comment: It is the exact opposite, this is written in pure C#.  The internal System.DateTimeParse class does the work.  For documentation just take a look at the Reference Source, `dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Globalization\DateTimeParse.cs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [this blog](http://blog.aasheim.org/2008/04/dont-use-datetimeparse-use.html), which says:

> It seems that very few people know that DateTime.Parse() is COM
>   dependent, evil one. Moreover, even in Microsoft.NET, there is no
>   assurance that such string that DateTime.Parse() accepts on your
>   machine is acceptable under other machines. Basically DateTime.Parse()
>   is for newbies who don't mind unpredictable behavior.

It appears that the author's choice of words isn't great; what they appear to be trying to warn the reader about is that `DateTime.Parse` is *culture*-dependent - the success/failure/result of a parse-operation will depend on the current culture. This is important for developers to note when they are trying to work with text representing date-times in a culture-sensitive/independent manner.

That said, it's of little relevance whether or not `Parse` has an actual COM-dependency or not. Since it's not directly documented, the implementation could be changed without notice by adding/removing COM dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is COM dependent. From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163824.aspx):

> There are two parsing methods you can use to parse your strings: Parse and ParseExact. The Parse method's functionality is rooted in COM (which was itself rooted to older versions of Visual Basic) and conversions from string to date happened no matter what the cost. The risks of improper parsing are an unfortunate side effect, one that is visible to people who have to work with both *dd/mm/yy* and *mm/dd/yy* dates. The DateTime.Parse method in the Microsoft .NET Framework has goals much like its predecessors, but unfortunately it suffers from some of the same problems. The code is slower since the extra checking takes time, and there will always be some new format that is not properly detected. In those older products, you may remember, the behavior was sometimes disparagingly referred to as "evil date parsing."

Comment: That says "rooted in COM". It doesn't say anything about being "COM dependent" (not that I have any idea what that even means). For all we know, the article is commenting on the legacy of the function. *Lots* of things in the .NET Framework have a legacy in COM, particularly the things derived from the world of VB before .NET (i.e., VB 6), which was based entirely on COM.

Comment: Cody, that is exactly my thought.